# How to create a snipping tool that works like Win+V clipboard history?

Tags: sql, ruby, windows

Guys
I work in IT support and have very little coding experience. I use a lot of tools during the day and if I where to alter any of them I would alter the snipping tool. I use it for taking snapshots of error-messages etc. that pops up on our clients computers. Every time I take a snapshot I have to choose to give it a name and have it saved in some folder. Doesn't seems so frustrating right? Well I probably take 15-30 of those a day, often while being on the phone and remote controlling some clients computer, i save snapshots with names I cannot remember and it chugs up space making it hard to find the correct snapshots later when I need it for troubleshooting and logging. What I need is a simple snipping tool that works like Win+V, clipboard history, id like my snipping tool to snap pictures and be logged in av archive much like the copy/cut history in my clipboard. That way I can scroll down and find correct image without searching through file explorer. How can I begin to do this, should I find an open source snipping tool out there and try editing it or should I just start from scratch? If so, what language should I write in and how to know where to begin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using lightshot software its simple and easy
you can also use this to upload your screenshots in cloud
https://app.prntscr.com/en/index.html